# Matrixes and modulo of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $N$-dimensional space. Consider the function $\kappa$ which maps a square $N\times N$ matrix $M$ into the scalar field

$v\mapsto \lvert Mv \rvert$ (for $v$ being a vector).

<del>Is the function $\kappa$ injective?</del> The function $\kappa$ is not injective because all rotations of the space map to the same scalar field. But is $\kappa$ locally injective almost everywhere?

If it isn't in which way we may limit the set of all $N\times N$ matrixes to make it injective?

Comment: How is the map $v \to \vert Mv \vert$ a vector field?  $\vert Mv\vert$ is a scalar quantity, isn't it?

Comment: Hm, it isn't injective: Take matrix $M'=-M$. But can $\lvert Mv \rvert$ be equal to $\lvert M'v \rvert$ if $M\ne M'$ and $M\ne -M'$?

Comment: Is $v$ fixed or a variable?  If it is a variable, can it be an arbitrary vector field?

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: $v$ is a variable taking arbitrary vector values

Comment: What if we replace $\lvert Mv\rvert$ with $v^T M v$?

Comment: Under the standard norm $|Mv|=v^TM^TMv$

Comment: @ellya: Why they are equal?

Comment: This is the Euclidean norm right?

Comment: @ellya: Yes, this is the Euclidean norm

Comment: Then I am correct, except I'm missing a square root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R(\varphi)$ be the rotation around some fixed axis by the angle $\varphi$.

A neighborhood around a matrix $M$ contains the matrices $R(\varphi)M$ if $\varphi$ is sufficiently small, but clearly $R(\varphi)M$ and $M$ map vectors to vectors of the same length, so the function $\kappa$ is not locally injective.

---

If you want to restrict your matrices, suppose that you have two invertible matrices $M$ and $N$ that give the same function. Then $MN^{-1}$ is an isometry.

Reflections and other symmetries are not a problem because they do not link matrices that are close to each other. So in some sense my example is the only one and you could eliminate it by fixing the image of one vector.

In conclusion, your function is locally injective if you restrict to invertible matrices that fix the first basis vector.

If you want injective, you have to eliminate the symmetries as well, for example by demanding positivity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on my main question. But I have also an other question: In which way we may limit the set of all $N\times N$ matrixes to make it injective?